# Read PT1000 with Raspberry PI3 Windows 10 iot

Tags: uwp, raspberry-pi3, temperature, windows-iot-core-10

I'm planing on building a simple app, to read 4 PT1000 temperature sensors.

I currently have a pcf8574a chip with 4 analog inputs, but how do I read the values within the UWP app?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Do I have to buy another chip or?

Answer (score 1):

Generally,the PCF8574A chip is used to expand input/output (I/O) for the two-line bidirectional bus (I2C). The PT1000 temperature sensor has one I2C interface,and Raspberry Pi3 supports I2C interface.
[image]

You can connect the 4 sensor to the Raspberry Pi3 via a breadboard, the Raspberry Pi3 looks as master, and the four sensor as slave. I think you should understand how the I2C bus works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply..

I changed to use the DS18B20 temp sensor, witch can be used directly on the Raspberry PI3 and Windows IoT using the 1-wire library.

Guide can be found here: https://www.hackster.io/selom/1-wire-ds18b20-sensor-on-windows-10-iot-core-raspberry-pi-2-7d9b67